# php - put separate words from textarea into variables

Tags: php, html

I need to scan tetxarea input text for marked words and put them in variables.

```
 <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="put some text" name="text"></textarea>
```

For example, the text in textarea is

```
 Every [day] I go to the [shop].
```

When the form is POSTed, the words in brackets have to be passed in variables, that are automatically generated, it has to be like that

```
 $word1 = "day";
 $word2 = "shop";
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Let us know if you run into any problems.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question? this site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/requirements lists.

Comment: Sidenote: `<textarea>` does not have a "type" as in your `type="text"` which is invalid.

Comment: @MarcB I myself can't wait for next Christmas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use preg_match_all, like

```
preg_match_all ( "/\[([^\]]+)\]/ism", $textarea, $matches );
```

$matches will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [day]
            [1] => [shop]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => day
            [1] => shop
        )

)
```

and $matches[1] will contain an array with your words.

Comment: Indeed. However, you probably haven't noticed that `<textarea>` does not have a "type" as in their `type="text"` which is invalid. It should be added to your answer ;-)

Comment: I think `[day]` and `[shop]` this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try something like this:

```
    <?php
        $textAreaText = $_POST["text"]; 
        preg_match("#(\[.*\])#si", $textAreaText, $matches); //<== MATCH EVERY TEXT WITHIN []

        // THE MATCHES ARRAY CONTAINS ANY TEXT ENCLOSED WITHIN []
        var_dump($matches); 

        // HOWEVER, YOU MAY HAVE TO ACCESS THE VARIABLES USING NUMBERS LIKE:
        // $matches[1]... etc
        // OR YOU COULD USE A LOOP AND CREATE VARIABLES OUT OF THE $matches ARRAY LIKE SO:
        $arrWords     = array();

        foreach($matches as $iKey=>$match){
            if($iKey != 0){
                $key            = "word" . $iKey;
                $arrWords[$key] = $match;
            }
        }

        // EXTRACT THE DATA IN THE ARRAY INTO VARIABLES:
        extract($arrWords);

        // NOW YOU COULD DO SOMETHING LIKE 
        echo $word1; // ASSUMING YOU HAVE AT LEAST 1 WORD WRAPPED WITHIN []
        echo $word2; // ASSUMING YOU HAVE UP TO 2 WORDS WRAPPED WITHIN []
        echo $word3; // ASSUMING YOU HAVE UP TO 3 WORDS WRAPPED WITHIN []
```